# Doesn't return expected concatenate String

Tags: java, string, if-statement, char, jvm

I improved solution for [startOz](https://codingbat.com/prob/p199720) task from CodingBat. I found better solution from previous one and when I tested it I got an unexpected solution in one test case.

```
public String startOz(String str) {
   String result = (str.indexOf('o') == 0 ? "o" : "").concat(str.indexOf('z') == 1 ? "z" : "");
   return result;
  }
```

```
// test case:
String str = "zzzz";
System.out.println("test=" + startOz(str));
```

I don't understand why I get empty String for result when I expected to get test=z

Comment: You have a method inside another method. Is that just a typo?

Comment: debug the code I would say!

Comment: Create a full and concrete [mcve] please.

Comment: `str.indexOf('z')` won't return `1` if `str=="zzzz"`, it will be `0`

Comment: You are assuming everybody knows what the `startOz` task is, and what the previous solution was. Please [edit] your question and add links and a short description (in case the links disappear in time). Questions on StackOverflow are not just for you - they are for every coder yet to come.

Comment: `indexOf` is not an efficient way of doing this, because it will scan over more of the string than necessary if the condition isn't met. Use `str.charAt(0) == 'o'` instead (with suitable bounds checks).

Comment: @ernest_k Yes, it was typo. I fixed, thanks! RealSkeptic, I am sorry, it is fixed now.  Andy Turner, It is good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`str.indexOf('z') == 1` returns false because [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) "*returns the index within this string of the **first occurrence** of the specified character*". In your case, `str.indexOf('z')` is zero because zero is the first occurrence.

There is [a version of this method which takes an additional argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int,%20int)) that defines which index to start from, so you could use the following to check whether Z is the second character:

```
str.indexOf('z', 1) == 1
```

That said, a better approach to this problem is probably to use [`charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)):

```
if (str.charAt(0) == 'o') //...
if (str.charAt(1) == 'z') //...
```

Comment: Thank You for clear explaining and for solution in mine case!

Answer (score 9):

because string index starts from 0

```
str.indexOf('z') == 1 is false

str.indexOf('z') == 0 is true
```

Answer (score 7):

There is no `'o'` character in your test `String`, so you're concatenating an empty `String` with empty `String` since the first index of `'z'` character is 0. `indexOf` returns the first matching index, so it's 0, not 1.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it returned empty string because the result of the indexOf condition is empty String.

```
"zzzz"
```

This part return to empty String because there is no "o" character

```
(str.indexOf('o') == 0 ? "o" : "") //Equals to ""
```

Then this also return empty because "z" was index 0.

```
(str.indexOf('z') == 1 ? "z" : "") //Equals to ""
```

The indexOf return the first character matching index number so the index of "z" was 0.
 There you have it.

Comment: +1 for your sarcastic comment, you are late to this answer as @Michel already answered it in details,But still upvoting for  REP :p

Comment: ＠Ravi it's better to be late than never.